# problems with background position

Tags: css, background-position

My question is why I can't go futher on the gif and select position: `-60px`. I've been trying with any lucky... any suggestions? I wanted to show you this on jsFiddle but dont know how to upload gif to the site.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1> Main Content</h1>
        <div id="icon">

          <a href="#row_01" title="01A">01A</a>    </div>
    <h2>H2 level heading </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquam,  justo convallis luctus rutrum, erat nulla fermentum diam, at nonummy quam  ante ac quam. Maecenas urna purus, fermentum id, molestie in, commodo  porttitor, felis. Nam blandit quam ut lacus. Quisque ornare risus quis  ligula. Phasellus tristique purus a augue condimentum adipiscing. Aenean  sagittis. Etiam leo pede, rhoncus venenatis, tristique in, vulputate at, odio.</p>
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
<!-- end #container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#icon a
{
    background-image: url(../img/icon.gif);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -99999px;



    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#icon a:hover, #icon a:focus
{
    background-position:  -30px 0;
}

#icon a.selected, #icon a.selected:hover

{
    background-position:  -60px 0;
}
```

Comment: What is width and height of the gif? By the way you can use **data URI** protocol to encode the gif and then easily put it on jsfiddle :)

Comment: @ karolis I thought dat thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem, as long as the image actually is at least 90 wide.

Here is your code with a placeholder image, and code that toggles the `selected` class when you click on the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/wwRed/

Comment: @Guffa! but with this jquery code wont work right? I mean only using the css-code?

Comment: @YoniGeek: What do you mean? You have specified that the anchor element should have the class `selected` for the third state to be activated, so you need some way to set that class.

Comment: @Guffa of course sorry! what if I dont use any class...is it posible to do without js ?

Comment: @YoniGeek: That depends on what you want to do. From the class name that you used I suppose that you want to select the image in some way? What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Guffa Im just want to keep choosing part of the gif-picture wihtout using jquery u think is posible? maybe not?

Comment: @YoniGeek: How should this choosing be done? What action should result in a selection?

Comment: @YoniGeek: I am not a mind reader, I have still no idea how you want it to work.

Comment: @Guffa I understand! well what I want to do is the samething like u did on yr ex. but not using jquery just pure css...

Comment: @YoniGeek: That is not possible. You can't handle click events using only CSS.